# Ambiente de desenvolvimento para ReactJS

Tags: visual-studio, react, npm

Utilizo o *Visual Studio* com *Asp.Net* e *C#* há alguns anos e agora estou terminando alguns cursos de *ReactJS*. Porém estou tendo dificuldades com o ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Nenhum dos cursos utilizou o *Visual Studio*. Apenas o VS Code. E as aplicações durante os cursos são criadas utilizando o *NPM* do *Node*.

Atualmente consigo criar um projeto no *Visual Studio* e instalar o *ReactJS* + *Babel* sem problemas, pois são apenas *libs* que podem ser importadas no *HTML*... Mas quando o assunto é dependências, módulos e outras coisas que normalmente são instaladas pelo *NPM* não sei o que fazer ou não consigo achar um equivalente que funcione bem no *Visual Studio*.

Quais bibliotecas são recomendadas? Como ultrapassar essa difícil relação entre *NPM* e *VS*?

Comment: Você consegue colocar os comandos do npm no próprio prompt de comando do windows. Vc só precisa entrar na pasta do projeto

Comment: Se eu der um "npm install" dentro da pasta do projeto, não estarei apenas jogando os arquivos do pacote para o mesmo diretório? Essa é a forma 
 de instalação recomendada para usuários do Visual Studio?

Comment: Isso mesmo. O padrão para instalação de pacotes no react independe da IDE.

Comment: Eu particularmente gosto das coisas separadas, ou seja, front-end no vsCode, back-end no visual studio.

Comment: Mas nada impede que se use a mesma IDE para as duas atividades.

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue colocar os comandos do npm no próprio prompt de comando do windows. Vc só precisa entrar na pasta do projeto.
O padrão para instalação de pacotes no react independe da IDE.